# Create two full page vertical lines in CSS

Tags: html, css

Using them to divide the page and add bordering on the sides to my whole content

So looks like this

```
   | content  |
```

but full page

Comment: Did you try anything ? If so then what happened ... show us what you tried.

Comment: Do you want three functional columns, or just one centered div that holds content?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this site: [In Search of the Holy Grail](http://alistapart.com/article/holygrail) that explains how to accomplish the three column layout in html.

Answer (score 0):

unless I misunderstood the question, you can just use this:

```
body{
  border-left: 1px solid;
  border-right: 1px solid;
}
```

[Here's the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yTuda/2/)

Comment: Hi, when i use that code with margins it brings all my content in the page more. Is there a way to make them not interfere with existing content but still be left and right offset?

Comment: @rob1994 I'm not sure exactly what you mean. Could you replicate the problem with http://www.jsfiddle.net ? What you could try, is this though: http://jsfiddle.net/yTuda/3/ Use margin on a specific div, instead of the body

Answer (score 0):

Make height 100% on html and body, and set border-left and border-right on body.

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 1000px; // width of your fixed width page, in pixels
  border-left: 1px solid;
  border-right: 1px solid;
}
```